# How to escape strings with numeric character references in Java

Tags: character-encoding, escaping, html-entities, character-reference

Hello and thank you for reading my post.

The Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml3() and StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4() functions allow, in particular, to convert characters with an acute (like é, à...) in a string into 
character entity references which have the format &name; where name is a case-sensitive alphanumeric string.

How can I get the escaped string of a given string with numeric character references instead (&#nnnn; or &#xhhhh; where nnnn is the code point in decimal form, and hhhh is the code point in hexadecimal form)?

I actually need to escape strings for a XML document which doesn't know about such entities as & eacute;, & agrave; etc.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, I wrote a method which takes a string as an argument and replaces, in this string, character entity references (like `&eacute;`) with their corresponding numeric character references (`&#233;` in this case).

I used this W3C list of references: http://www.sagehill.net/livedtd/xhtml1-transitional/xhtml-lat1.ent.html

Nota: It would be great to be able to pass another argument to the `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()` method to tell it whether we would like character entity references or numeric character references in the output string...

Answer (score 2):

Create your `CharacterTranslator`:

```
CharacterTranslator XML_ESCAPE = StringEscapeUtils.ESCAPE_XML11.with(
    NumericEntityEscaper.between(0x7f, Integer.MAX_VALUE) );
```

and use it:

```
XML_ESCAPE.translate(…)
```

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a lot of time!